# Htaccess .html that redirect from query and one not from query

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have problem open an url from page .html extension after i used a hataccess
with the following code

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ single.php?post=$1 [L]
```

So when i open my page with myhtml.html, the page trying to find from single.php?post=myhtml.html

Please give an idea for better htaccess code that can open .html extension not from the query

Sorry for bad english... Thanks before

Comment: @pfnuesel when editing a post, please remove any salutations, TIA etc. clutter as well. If you're fixing something, fix it in a single go.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `^(.*)\.html`, anything you put before .html on your URL it will be assigned to `$1`. So you should use something like this.

```
 RewriteRule ^myhtml.html$ single.php [L]     
 RewriteRule ^/myhtml/(.*)$ /single.php?post=$1 [L] //This is a dynamic url
```

In this example, when you put `myhtml.com` on your url it will look for `single.php` and load it and when you say `myhtml/any-url.html` that `any-url` will be assigned to `$1`. 
I hope it helps out.